# Update column by calling function is very slow - how to improve? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I need to update some column by calling a function. It takes a too long time.

How can I improve it? What could be the reason it takes so long?

I realized that scalar-function takes more time than a table-function, but I have no idea how to convert this to a table function, is there perhaps another way to do this?

The code that updates:

```
UPDATE EDBNationalInsuranceMortgageLoad_tmp
SET IsDead = dbo.GetIsDead(IdentityNumber1, @FileId) -- the function
```

The code of the function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIsDead]
    (@IdentityNumber1 NVARCHAR(9),
     @FileId INT)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @mateIdentityNumber NVARCHAR(9);
    DECLARE @fullRow1_tmp TABLE 
                          (
                              IdentityNumber NVARCHAR(9), 
                              MateIdentityNumber NVARCHAR(9), 
                              DeathDate NVARCHAR(8)
                          );
    DECLARE @fullRow2_tmp TABLE
                              IdentityNumber NVARCHAR(9), 
                              MateIdentityNumber NVARCHAR(9), 
                              DeathDate NVARCHAR(8)
                          );
    DECLARE @countRows2 INT
    DECLARE @isDead1 INT = 0
    DECLARE @isDead2 INT = 0

    SET @mateIdentityNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 MateIdentityNumber 
                               FROM MortgageReturnParticipationBase
                               WHERE IdentityNumber = @IdentityNumber1
                                 AND MortgageReturnParticipationStatusId = 1)

    INSERT INTO @fullRow1_tmp 
        SELECT TOP 1 IdentityNumber1, IdentityNumber2, DeathDate 
        FROM EDBNationalInsuranceMortgageLoad_tmp
        WHERE IdentityNumber1 = @IdentityNumber1
          AND IsRowError = 0
          AND FileId = @FileId

    SET @isDead1 = (SELECT 1 
                    FROM @fullRow1_tmp
                    WHERE DeathDate IS NOT NULL)

    IF @mateIdentityNumber = 0
    BEGIN
        IF (@isDead1 = 1) 
            RETURN 0;
        ELSE
            RETURN 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @fullRow2_tmp 
            SELECT TOP 1 IdentityNumber1, IdentityNumber2, DeathDate 
            FROM EDBNationalInsuranceMortgageLoad_tmp
            WHERE IdentityNumber1 = @mateIdentityNumber
              AND IsRowError = 0
              AND FileId = @FileId

        SET @countRows2 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @fullRow2_tmp)

        IF @countRows2 = 0  
            RETURN 2;

        SET @isDead2 = (SELECT 1 FROM @fullRow2_tmp WHERE DeathDate IS NOT NULL)

        IF (@isDead1 IS NULL OR @isDead2 IS NULL OR @isDead1 = 0 OR @isDead2 = 0)
            RETURN 1;

        IF (@isDead1 = 1 AND @isDead2 = 1)
            RETURN 0;   
    END

    RETURN NULL;
END
```

I tried to convert it to a table-function, but it worked slowly:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetIsDeadTableFunc (
@IdentityNumber1 nvarchar(9),
@FileId INT)

RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN



select (case when (b.MateIdentityNumber > 0 and b.MateIdentityNumber 
                   not in (SELECT IdentityNumber1 
                             from EDBNationalInsuranceMortgageLoad_tmp
                            where IsRowError=0
                              and FileId=@FileId)) 
         then 2
       when (b.MateIdentityNumber = 0
             and DeathDate is null) 
        or (b.MateIdentityNumber > 0 and b.MateIdentityNumber in (SELECT IdentityNumber1 
                                                                                  from EDBNationalInsuranceMortgageLoad_tmp
                                                                                 where IsRowError=0
                                                                                   and FileId=@FileId
                                                                                   and (DeathDate is null or DeathDate is not null)) 
             and DeathDate is null)
         or (b.MateIdentityNumber > 0 and b.MateIdentityNumber in (SELECT IdentityNumber1 
                                                                                  from EDBNationalInsuranceMortgageLoad_tmp
                                                                                 where IsRowError=0
                                                                                   and FileId=@FileId
                                                                                   and DeathDate is null) -- אמור להיות עוד פונה והוא נמצא בקובץ חי
             and DeathDate is not null) -- פונה 1 נפטר
        then 1 

        else 0 end) as IsDead
from EDBNationalInsuranceMortgageLoad_tmp e
join MortgageReturnParticipationBase b on b.IdentityNumber = e.IdentityNumber1
WHERE e.IdentityNumber1 = @IdentityNumber1
  and IsRowError=0
  and FileId=@FileId
  and b.MortgageReturnParticipationStatusId=1



GO
```

Comment: Scalar functions are notoriously slow. What are you trying to achieve with the function? You would be far better off use a **inline** table-value function here.

Comment: I know, But I have no idea how to exercise it

Comment: Neither do we if we don't know what the function is meant to be doing.

Comment: I change it to table-function, but it took me alot of time also

Comment: Have you look at the **actual execution plan** of your query? That should tell you where your code is loosing all that time, and might offer insights as to what to do (use proper indexing, for instance)

Comment: Did you change it to an inline table value function, or a multi-line function? Can you include the new version in your question? And, as marc_s said, the execution plan will really help. [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Always make my neck hairs stand up with the variable is called `@IdentityNumber`, or `DeathDate` - but the datatype is `NVARCHAR(x)` :....... please use the **most appropriate** datatype - ***ALWAYS*** - a "number" is numeric - use `int` or `decimal` - a "Date" is a `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` - both should **NOT** be stored as `nvarchar(x)` just out of lazyness of not wanting to think about what proper datatype to choose.....

Comment: And let's add to the list of concerns - "select top 1" without an order by clause is almost always a logic error (and usually a kludge).